# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'geometry'

Tags: tkinter

How can i fix this error?

```
try:
from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter.ttk import *

from idlelib.tree import ScrolledCanvas, FileTreeItem, TreeNode


import os

import tkinter.messagebox




class FileManager(Tk):

def createWidgets(self):
    self.menu = Menu(self)
    self.submenu = Menu(self.menu)
    self.menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu = self.submenu)

    self.submenu.add_command(label='New Project')
    self.submenu.add_command(label='Open...')
    self.submenu.add_separator()
    self.submenu.add_command(label='Save')
    self.submenu.add_command(label='Save As...')
    self.submenu.add_separator()
    self.submenu.add_command(label='Exit')

    self.editmenu = Menu(self.menu)
    self.menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu = self.editmenu)
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Undo')
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Redo')
    self.editmenu.add_separator()
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Cut')
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Copy')
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Copy Path')
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Paste')
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Select All')
    self.editmenu.add_separator()
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Replace')
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Rename')
    self.editmenu.add_command(label='Move to...')

    self.optionsmenu = Menu(self.menu)
    self.menu.add_cascade(label='Options', menu = self.optionsmenu)
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Very Large Icons')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Large Icons')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Medium Icons')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Small Icons')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='List')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Tiles')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Details')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Content')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='List')
    self.optionsmenu.add_separator()
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Show Libraries')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='Show All Folders')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='')
    self.optionsmenu.add_command(label='')

def __init__(self,master=None):
    Tk.__init__(self)
    self.createWidgets()
    self.config(menu=self.menu)
    self.master.geometry("1000x500+200+100")
    self.master.title("File Explorer")
    self.pack(side="top")

    self.entry=tkinter.ttk.Entry(master)
    self.entry.pack(side="top",fill=X)
    self.entry.focus()


    self.sc = ScrolledCanvas(master, highlightthickness=0, takefocus=1)
    self.sc.frame.pack(expand=0, fill="both", side="left")
    item = FileTreeItem("C:")
    node = TreeNode(self.sc.canvas, False, item)
    node.expand()

    self.fr=tkinter.ttk.Frame(master)
    self.fr.pack(side="top",expand=True,fill="both")

    self.contents=tkinter.ttk.Label(self.fr,text="Contents", style="BW.TLabel")
    self.contents.pack(side="top",expand=False,fill=X)


    self.entry.bind("<Return>",lambda e:self.buttonClick())



    self.button=ttk.Button(self.entry,text="Find result",width=20)
    self.button.pack(side="right")
    self.button.config(command=self.buttonClick)

    self.fr2=Text(self.fr)
    self.scrollbar=tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar(self.fr2,command=self.fr2.yview)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side="right",fill=Y)
    self.fr2.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.fr2.pack(side="top",expand=True,fill="both")


    self.fr3=tkinter.ttk.Frame(master)
    self.fr3.pack(side="right",expand=True,fill="both")
    self.open=ttk.Button(self.fr3,text='Open',command=self.openButton)
    self.open.pack(side="left",fill=X,expand=True)

    self.delete=ttk.Button(self.fr3,text="Delete",command=self.eraseButton)
    self.delete.pack(side="left",fill=X,expand=True)


def buttonClick(self):
    orisma=self.entry.get()
    os.system(orisma)
    self.fr2.delete('1.0','end')
    try:
        g=os.listdir(orisma)
        times=len(g)
        self.fr2.insert('end',orisma)
        self.fr2.insert('end',' -->')
        self.fr2.insert('end','\n')
        self.fr2.insert('end','\n')
        for i in range(times):
            s=g[i]

            self.fr2.insert('end',s)
            self.fr2.insert('end','\n')
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Δεν εντοπίστηκε η διαδρομή!")



def openButton(self):
    ranges = self.fr2.tag_ranges(SEL)
    if ranges:
        var=str(self.fr2.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST))
        try:
            end=var.index('\n')
            if end>0:
                print(var[:end])
        except:
            print(var)
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("TclError ", "Δεν επιλέχθηκε αρχείο!")


def onClick(self):
    pass

def __str__(self):
    pass

def focus_get(self):
    pass


def eraseButton(self):
    pass

if __name__=="__main__":
root = FileManager()
root.mainloop()
```

I can't have a menu bar. I used to have Frame instead of Tk in the class but the menu can't work with Frame so I changed it and still nothing works. Is there any way that I can define root=Tk() and pass it in the class somehow?
I am new in Python and I don't have knowledge of any programming language. Also, my English sucks a bit so please show some understanding:P
Anyway, if there is someone who may have free time to see a small part of my code and help me find a way to fix this error I would be really happy :D

Comment: Hi there, thanks for joining StackOverflow, might be worth editing your example to create a more minimal code sample. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some advice.

Comment: It is because `self.master` in FileManager class is None.  Actually self.master is useless as FileManager is inherented from Tk which is the topmost level container.  Just change `self.master.geometry(...)` to `self.geometry(...)`.